# Converting nameless JSONArray to List using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to fill a List object by using retrofit. Currently, I'm getting a null pointer exception whenever I call the List object. How do I get retrofit to work properly?

My call to Retrofit:

```
@Override
public void success(List<Game> gameList, Response response) {
    mGameSeason = gameList;
}
```

My Retrofit implementation:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static ApiInterface sApiService;

    public static ApiInterface getApiClient() {
        if (sApiService == null) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://www.someapi.com")
                .build();

            sApiService = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }
        return sApiService;
    }

    public interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("path")
        void getGames(Callback<List<Game>> callback);
    }
}
```

My Game POJO:

```
public class Game {

    @Expose
    private String gameID;
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @Expose
    private String awayTeam;
    @Expose
    private String homeTeam;
    @Expose
    private String gameType;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The gameID
     */
    public String getGameID() {
        return gameID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param gameID
     * The gameID
     */
    public void setGameID(String gameID) {
        this.gameID = gameID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param date
     * The date
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The awayTeam
     */
    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param awayTeam
     * The awayTeam
     */
    public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The homeTeam
     */
    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param homeTeam
     * The homeTeam
     */
    public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The gameType
     */
    public String getGameType() {
        return gameType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param gameType
     * The gameType
     */
    public void setGameType(String gameType) {
        this.gameType = gameType;
    }
}
```

The JSON Response:

```
[  
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030416",
      "date":"Mon Jun 11, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "homeTeam":"Los Angeles Kings",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   },
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030415",
      "date":"Sat Jun 09, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"Los Angeles Kings",
      "homeTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   },
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030414",
      "date":"Wed Jun 06, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "homeTeam":"Los Angeles Kings",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   },
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030413",
      "date":"Mon Jun 04, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "homeTeam":"Los Angeles Kings",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   },
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030314",
      "date":"Mon May 21, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"New York Rangers",
      "homeTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   },
   {  
      "gameID":"2011030313",
      "date":"Sat May 19, 2012",
      "awayTeam":"New York Rangers",
      "homeTeam":"New Jersey Devils",
      "gameType":"Playoffs"
   }
]
```

Comment: I missunderstood the question and deleted the answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare correctly your list mGameSeason before?
You can try to do something like this

```js
public void success(List<Game> gameList, Response response) {
            mGameSeason.clear();
            mGameSeason.addAll(gameList);
            gameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You will also need to define an adapter for your list if you haven't already done it.

Let me know if this helps

Here's what you can do for the adapter

```js
protected List<Game> mGameList;
protected LayoutInflater inflater;
protected Context mContext;

  public GameAdapter(List<Game> games, Context context) {
    this.mGameList = games;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
  }

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mGameList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Game getItem(int position) {
        return mGameList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;

        if(convertView==null){
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_game, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem(convertView);

            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolderItem);

        }else{
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Game game = getItem(position);

        // assign values if the object is not null
        if(game != null) {
          // set your layout here  
          viewHolderItem.nameGame.setText(game.getName());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

  static class ViewHolderItem {
    @InjectView(R.id.name_radio)
    TextView nameRadio;

    public ViewHolderItem(View v) {
      ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an adapter for the List<Game> object yet, how would I define the adapter for it?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, you need to create a GameAdapter object that implements BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

RestAdapter and your API interface should be used as a SINGLETON, it looks like you are not checking the rest adapter to be a singleton, try something like this in your fragment or activity:

```
    // Activity or fragment use
MyAwesomeApiInterface api;

MyAwesomeApiInterface getApi() {
    if (api == null) {
        api = getRestAdapter().create(MyAwesomeApiInterface.class);
    }
    return api;
}

Retrofit retrofit;

Retrofit getRestAdapter() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```